# How to get variant value inside content of SnackbarProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, snackbar

I am using [notistack](https://iamhosseindhv.com/notistack/demos#custom-snackbar) library for showing `snackbar` in my application. I wanted to customise the content of snackbar. Hence using `content` property of `snackbar`. I wanted to know whether the message variant is `success` or `warning` or `error`, and based on that I want to set the color. of toast. 
Below is a sandbox URL:
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hellman-2gcs0?file=/App.js

How can I get the variant value inside `ToastTemplate`?

Comment: Did you check my answer? Does it solve the issue?

Comment: No. Its not solving the problem. I wanted to get a variant inside template and not inside redux. Please see index.js `<SnackbarProvider content=`

Comment: check the update

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `export const enqueueSnackbar = (notification) => {` function you have the `notification` object, which has the `options` and `variant` that you can use:

```
export const enqueueSnackbar = (notification) => {
    const key = notification.options && notification.options.key;
    const variant = notification.options && notification.options.variant;
    console.log(variant);

    console.log(notification);
    return {
        type: ENQUEUE_SNACKBAR,
        notification: {
            ...notification,
            key: key || new Date().getTime() + Math.random(),
        },
    };
};
```

### Update

Since you want to variant inside the `SnackbarProvider`, you can pass the entire data (and not only the text-message) and use what you need inside.

```
export const enqueueSnackbar = notification => {
  const key = notification.options && notification.options.key;
  return {
    type: ENQUEUE_SNACKBAR,
    notification: {
      message: { ...notification },
      // ^ Instead of passing the text - I'm passing the entire object
      key: key || new Date().getTime() + Math.random()
    }
  };
};
```

Inside the SnackbarProvider:

```
<SnackbarProvider
  content={(key, notificationData) => {
    const message = notificationData.message;
    const variant = notificationData.options.variant
    console.log(variant);
    return <ToastTemplate id={key} message={message} />;
  }}
>
```

Check here the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ramanujan-1p7yw?file=/index.js